# Cannot get any macOS or Linux OS to install on iMac

Tags: imac, startup

I am having a strange issue with my Mid 2010 27 inch iMac - I get the chime, I can get into recovery partitions and into installer USBs no problem...but I can't seem to get a single install working. It'll just reboot a minute or two into installation. I can get into the desktop of an old Lion drive - but I get the "your computer needs to restart" error. It also failed halfway through internet recovery <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

I've already tried SMC and NVRAM resets of course.

Here is a picture of the kernel error I am getting. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoTI0.jpg

*Edit: attempt to make the original more legible [not hugely successful]*

[image]

Comment: What system versions have you tried?  I have the same iMac computer.

Comment: You cannot install MacOS on this computer. MacOS only runs on Motorola 68k and PowerPC CPUs, but this computer has an Intel CPU.

Comment: Try [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) to see if there’s anything going on with your system.  However based on past experience, it’s either the GPU or memory.  Memory is cheap to test, so I’d start there.

Comment: That was a typo, @JörgWMittag PowerPC Macs didn’t come with Internet a Recovery or we’re capable of running Lion.

Comment: OP is trying to install macOS, not MacOS.  His machine can run up to 10.13.6 High Sierra but cannot run systems beyond that.

Comment: I just tried running Apple Hardware Test - also fails about 20 seconds into loading up.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: check the disk.

A ten-year-old Mac is a likely candidate for a failed hard drive. Use Disk Utility to check the drive.

Secondly: check the rest of the hardware.

If you have a bootable system on an external USB drive, which you know boots on another Mac, see if that will work. If it doesn't, then the problem is likely a hardware fault.

Comment: I have tried on multiple external drives. I have 120/240/480GB solid states and ive tried on all of them - and a few HDD as well. I cannot get ANY mac operating system to run on this iMac. I also have multiple different RAM sticks (10600 and 12800) I have tried multiple ram configurations with different sticks and that does not seem to be the issue.

Comment: Then it's likely a hardware fault. Either see if there's a local Apple technician who will have a look at it, or call it a day.